# Why is this shader circle so much smaller than the passed radius?

Tags: javascript, math, shader, webgl

I'm developing a GLSL shader that draws out a circle based on a given center position and radius. For some reason I don't understand, the circle's radius does not match what I am passing. That is, when I pass in `100` for `u_radius`, the radius is instead `56`. I tried just doubling the value in the shader, and while it's close with that, it's still slightly inaccurate. Does anyone have any clue what could be causing the discrepancy?

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_pos;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;
uniform vec2 u_center; // the center of the circle in world coordinates

uniform float u_aspect; // aspect ratio. 1.7778 for my monitor (1920x1080)
uniform float u_radius; // radius. passing in 100

uniform vec2 u_canvasSize; // [ 1920, 1080 ]

void main() {
  vec4 c = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(u_center, 1)).xy, 0, 1); // center

  vec2 onePix = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_canvasSize; // the size of one pixel in clip-space

  float onePixLength = sqrt(onePix.x * onePix.x + onePix.y * onePix.y); // magnitude of one pixel

  float r = onePixLength * u_radius; // radius converted to clip-space

  vec2 dist = (v_pos.xy - c.xy) * vec2(u_aspect, 1.0); // distance from center to current shader point

  if (dist.x * dist.x + dist.y * dist.y > r * r) {
    discard;
  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because normalized device space coordinates are in range [-1.0, 1.0]. Therefore a factor of 2 is missing when calculating the pixel size:

<s>`vec2 onePix = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_canvasSize;`</s>

```c
vec2 onePix = vec2(2.0) / u_canvasSize;
```

Additionally, you need to calculate the side length of a pixel instead of the diagonal length. The width (x-dimension) is scaled by the aspect ratio. Therefore, you need to calculate the height of a pixel:

<s>`float onePixLength = sqrt(onePix.x * onePix.x + onePix.y * onePix.y);`</s>

```c
float onePixLength = onePix.y;
```

Note, `onePix.x * u_aspect` is equal to `onePix.y`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmm, this is close, but it's still not quite right. That is, if the radius is say, `250`, then the measured rendered radius is instead `279`. I wonder what is causing the difference?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Of course, because you compute the length of the diagonal, instead of the side length of a pixel.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh, I understand now. Thanks!! That fixed it